# Detect whether method was called on object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, methods, return, conditional-statements

**This is a general programming question, not specific to this code example.**

### How do I detect whether a particular method was called or not from within a function?

Imagine you want to be able to tell whether a particular method was called so that you can change what you return based on that.

```
var turtle = function() {
    var vars = {
        name: "Shelly",
        age: 103
    };

    this.actions = function() {
        var methods = {
            crawl: function() {
                //etc...
            },
            mutate: function() {
                //etc...
            },
            eat: function() {
                //etc...
            }
        };

      if (methodWasCalled) { // <- The part I don't know how to do
          return methods;
      } else {
          return this;
      }
        
    };
    if (methodWasCalled) { // <- The part I don't know how to do
        return vars;
    } else {
        return this;
    }
};
```

Based on the above example, someone could use: `turtle()` and get access to the 'vars' object, or they could use: `turtle().mutate()` and the turtle object would execute the block inside that function.

Comment: why would you need to code in this manner? I imagine there's a better way so what is your use case

Comment: unfortunately, I can't talk about the specific use case, but if we use the turtle analogy what might you do differently? what about the example given seems inefficient or not as 'good'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the caller access the [arguments object.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/87dw3w1k(v=vs.94).aspx)

```
alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
```

Callee refers to the function being executed, in your case mutate.  It has a property that references the caller.

Best thing for you to do is break out a debugging kit (I personally prefer Chrome/IE) and explore the object to see the full details of info you want to see.